# table-layout:fixed use text-overflow:ellipse and a second text showing

Tags: css, tablelayout

I am quite new to css, and i was searching already for hours for a solution to this problem.
I have a fixed layout table in a resizable container.
i have a resizing column, that has 2 texts, the first should do a text-overflow:ellipse while the second should always show (if possible).
The requirement is to not show all the text in a table cell if it doesnt fit, but display the last 5 letters.
I figured ill put 2 spans in a td, and give a width to the second, but the width is ignored. When i tried to float the element (i can only float left, cause floating right will put the last 5 letters to the end on an long column with little text, which is not ok), left, but then the first div is not getting smaller so the text-overflow:ellipse is not applied.

E.g i need when td is short:

```
|Hello budd...ight?|
```

and

```
|Hello buddy ho...ight?|
```

but when td is long:

```
|Hello buddy how is it going tonight?                       |
```

This seems to be a fairly common requirement, so how can i achieve it?
I do not want any javascript, im quite sure it can be solved by css, and maybe some extra divs...

my html:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
<colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col width="200px"/>
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="first">Hello buddy how is it going ton</span>
        <span class="second">ight?</span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my css:

```
table
{
     width: 90%;
     margin: 10px;   
}

tr
{
    height: 100px;
}
td
{
    width: 50%;   
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    while-space:nowrap;
}

span.first {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid red;   

}
span.second
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?
Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the text always one-line, or can it flow into multiple lines in some situations?

Comment: Anyone? It cannot be that hard!!! Please please!!!

Comment: I've come up with several methods that work if the TD is the size of the text or smaller... but nothing that works if the TD is wider than the text. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was [able to get something working](https://jsfiddle.net/hUQNh/)... here's the changed CSS:

```css
span.first {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
/* --- everything below this line is new --- */
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5ex;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
span.second
{
    width: 4ex;
    margin-left: -5ex;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Compatible in: [image: Chrome]
 [image: Firefox]
 [image: IE9]

I have not tested Opera or IE<9 (although I can pretty much guarantee that IE7 won't run it, because the MDN states that [IE introduced `box-sizing` with IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))

---

Explanation:

#### .first

`float: left;` lets both spans use the same line when combined with `display: inline-block;`
`padding-right: 5ex;` makes room for the last five characters (works with MOST fonts)
`max-width: 100%;` lets the first span grow up to (but not beyond) the width of the `TD`
`display: inline-block;` needed to use `max-width` effectively
`box-sizing: border-box;` puts padding inside content area (`max-width`) use prefixes because Firefox doesn't support the non-prefixed variant yet.

#### .second

`width: 4ex;` because it gets screwy if you use `5ex` with the below
`margin-left: -5ex;` makes `.second` sidle up to the edge of the text area for `.first`

**Note:** You can change the `ex` values to suit your needs, but make sure both
*`margin-left`*`== -(`*`padding-right`*`)`
*`width`*`<=`*`padding-right`*`- 0.5`